# Apple Store Connect screenshot for 5,5 iPhone model

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot

I'm trying to publish an application on the App Store, but it's requesting screenshots from an iPhone with a screen size of 5.5 inches. The iPhone in question should be an iPhone 8 Plus. However, when I try to run it via the Xcode emulator, I'm unable to do so because it doesn't support iOS 16.0, which is the minimum required OS for my application. How can I obtain these screenshots to upload to App Store Connect?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to manually install another iOS version but my app won't run

Comment: I have no trouble creating an iPhone 8 Plus simulator with iOS 16.4. Have you installed any iOS 16.x simulator runtimes?

Comment: I downloaded 16.1, but still I can't add an iPhone 8 Plus with that OS. XCode doesn't show it to me if I click on "OS Version"

Comment: Facing the same problem. I can not download the iOS simulators because the download stops after a while.

Answer (score -1):

> Apple's answer:
>
> Some screenshots are always required. Even though your app will not run on those devices, it will still be displayed and just say it is not downloadable on that device. Also, 5.5 screenshots are used for scaling up and down depending on the users device and what screenshots the developer has or has not provided. For a list of required screenshots

iPhone 8+ screen ratio is 9:16 You can use any iPhone with the same ratio. for example `iPhone SE (3rd gen)` which support iOS 16.0